# Are mysql prepared statement APIs thread safe?

Tags: mysql, c, multithreading, prepared-statement

I've been using libmysqlclient (_r) in a threaded program and I'm occasionally getting a lot of weird errors with calls like mysql_stmt_prepare and myql_stmt_bind_param/result.

I've read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api-threaded-clients.html but it made no mention of any prepared statements. Individual API pages such as http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-stmt-prepare.html also has no mention of threads.

At this stage I can only assume that they are not thread safe.

Or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: You are correct. Neither prepared statements nor even connections are thread-safe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using libmysqlclient in multi-threaded application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313686/using-libmysqlclient-in-multi-threaded-application)