# Using thread-safe libraries

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

I can think of two ways a thread-safe library can be used:

One is having a global instance of the library protected by a mutex, which is initialised by the main thread and used by worker threads, like so:

```
mutex g_lib_mutex;
lib_t g_lib;

thread:
    lock(&g_lib_mutex);
    /* use lib */
    unlock(&g_lib_mutex);


main:
    lib_init(&g_lib);
    start_threads(thread);

    lock(&g_lib_mutex);
    /* use lib */
    unlock(&g_lib_mutex);

    join_threads();
    lib_close(&g_lib);
```

The other, is for every thread to have a local instance of the library, something like this:

```
thread:
    lib_t g_lib;
    lib_init(&g_lib);
    /* use lib */
    lib_close(&g_lib);


main:
    start_threads(thread);
    lib_t g_lib;
    lib_init(&g_lib);
    /* use lib */
    lib_close(&g_lib);
```

Which of these ways is more correct / preferable?

Do I need to protect library calls with a global mutex in both cases?

I was trying to use libmysql and POSIX message queues in a multi-threaded application when this question crossed my mind.

Comment: Do you need/want to share an instance across threads?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313686/using-libmysqlclient-in-multi-threaded-application

Comment: @HannoBinder... I'm not sure, but in cases such as libmysql, where not all calls are thread-safe, looks like I may need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, only initialize a library once. Remember, all threads happen in the same process' memory space, so whatever you do to any global variables in thread X is true for all threads. Library initialization should happen only once per process.

Now, whether library calls are thread safe or must be protected by mutexes is a question of your library. Modern libraries should have definite documentation on what functions you're allowed to call from multiple threads. If that info is missing you can either

- assume the worst and encapsulate everything that changes something that the library deals with, or calls into the library, with a single global mutex, or
- read the source code of the library to figure out what might go wrong where, introduce security measures (mutexes/conditions) accordingly, and make sure that no one uses a different version of the library (where things might be different), or
- improve the documentation, send that patch to the upstream developers asking them to verify that what you document in thread-(un)safety is intentional and matches reality, (documentation patches are, for any project that I know of, always welcome) or
- modify the library itself to be thread safe (making yourself a hero).

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer @Marcus. 
But isn't it true that `thread-safe` libraries shouldn't have a global mutable state? And so initialising it more than once shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: No, that's not inherently true, @Zaxter. "Thread-safe" might just mean that there are some (or all) functions that can be called from different threads, but library initialization typically can't be one of these.

Comment: Aaahhh! It's not the first time I (wrongly) presumed something... Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: What do you mean by 'library initialization', though?

Comment: functions you have to call before you can start calling library functions, e.g. `lib_init(..)`.